# Refactor only selection black

Tags: python, pycharm

Is there a way to only refactor what's selected when using black? [I'm using black on PyCharm.](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/integrations/editors.html)

Comment: The answer under that question is outdated, if you don't mind installing an HTTP server on your machine to get the functionality, then currently [blackd](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage_and_configuration/black_as_a_server.html) is likely the best choice. It's either that or implementing your own selection for a region like in the linked answer.

Comment: I think I already have blackd (cf linked I provided in the original post). However, I don't think `blackd` has support for refactoring only a selection. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Actually, I just found that: https://godatadriven.com/blog/partial-python-code-formatting-with-black-pycharm/

Comment: Although that might not be blackd but black

Comment: The blog post you linked is the same solution as mine but running on Linux with a simpler CLI sed/bash interface. Because of that it simplifies a number of Windows specific problems like character encoding and clipboard. Now, I don't recall if there was a native region selection to blackd or if I just realized implementing the region using blackd would make things simpler on Windows (tried looking at it again, and blackd does not seem to have a region implementation natively atm). Which is always discounting the additional difficulties of configuring an HTTP server...

Comment: Oh yeh, so both answers (blog and yours) don't use `blackd` :/